# How to calculate Tor(R/I, R/J) ??

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

How can I prove that $\text{Tor}_1(R/I,R/J) = (I \cap J)/IJ$, where $R$ is a ring and $I, J$ ideals.

Moreover, if we suppose $R=I+J$, how do I prove that $\text{Tor}_1(R/I,R/J)=0$?

Ps: No, this is not a homework question.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: which Tor group do you mean?  In any case, it really does sound like homework to me.  Here's a hint: think about what happens if you apply Tor to an exact sequence like $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$.

Comment: I mean Tor_1 over the ring R. That is exactly what I did, but I get Tor(R/I x R/J) = Ker(I x R/I ----> A x A/J), where x is the tensor product, but then I don't know how to prove the equality.

Comment: Karl, thank you for the answer. It with the one below allowed me to have the solution. I really apreciate that.

Comment: I answered this a few days ago here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AmecOLp.eBY6594ZlKUkhPnsy6IX;_ylv=3?qid=20101130181406AACO2oQ

Comment: yes, I've already proved the first part, but now I can't see the second. Anyway thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:  1)  First prove that $I\otimes(R/J)=I/IJ$ .   2)  If $I+J=R$, write $1=i+j$ and use the fact that $x=1x$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It was very useful.

Concerning to 2), I think you don't understand what I asked. I need to prove that (I∩J) = IJ, using that Tor1(R/I,R/J)=(I∩J)/IJ and the fact that R=I+J. So I think if we prove that Tor vanishes in this case, we have the problem solved.

Once again thank you.

Comment: yes, that I know since the basic. lolol 

What I don't know is to prove that indirectly, I mean, using the fact that Tor(R/I,R/J)=(I∩J)/IJ. I must prove that tor vanishes to conclude that I∩J = IJ, see?

Comment: "I think you don't understand what I asked" is not the most polite way to put it.

Comment: $I+J = R \Rightarrow I \cap J = IJ$ is an easy exercise in the beginning of commutative algebra and does not involve any Tor-functors. 

Answer (score 7):

Although already pointed out by others that this is an easy exercise, the most obvious answer to the second question has been overlooked: since $I$ and $J$ are both in the annihilator of $\text{Tor}_1(R/I,R/J)$ (by functoriality) and $I+J=R$, the Tor module must be zero.